# BreezeJS return custom data when saving

Tags: asp.net, breeze, single-page-application

A typical action method for saving the changes sent from breeze.client would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {
     return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}
```

I've noticed that breeze on the client side has a callback function for a POST request that expects the structure of the returned value to be specific:

```
      success: function (httpResponse) {
            var data = httpResponse.data;
            httpResponse.saveContext = saveContext;
            var entityErrors = data.Errors || data.errors;
            if (entityErrors) {
                handleHttpError(deferred, httpResponse);
            } else {
                var saveResult = that._prepareSaveResult(saveContext, data);
                deferred.resolve(saveResult);
            }

        },
```

In my case I don't want to use `_contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);` to save the changes; I want to do it in my own way.

Is it possible to return any arbitrary structured data from the SaveChanges action method? Or for example, what would happen if we use a different ORM or a NoSQL db? How would we implement the SaveChanges API endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

you can return your own SaveResult object containting the entities 
to skip the save process dont return the entities from the OnBeforeSaveEntities function
breeze client will add them to manager once you return a SaveResult object

other option is to use your own implementation of breeze.contextprovider

hope this helps

Comment: That's if we use .NET on the back-end; I'm not using .NET; So, i'm afraid that, that won't work out so well for me.